# Second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation with some conditions

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions, inverse-function

I just started to solve second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation with boundaries condition I wanted to solve by `DSolve` but I know should be some singularities there so what you think it is better to do?

```
(y''[x]/ y[x]) + a (y'[x]/ y[x])^2 - (b (y'[x]/y[x]) )+ (c/(y[x])^2) - d =0
```

`a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are positive constants. Also `y[1]>0, y'[1]=1, y''[1]>0`

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Syntax note: Note that an equation has a double `==`. Set equal to (assigning a value) is done with a single `=`.

Comment: `DSolve` can solve the ODE for some specific numeric values for the parameters but not for `{a = 2, b = 2, c = 1, d = 6}` (V12.2). The failure suggests a general solution might not be possible.

Comment: So how to plot y'/y ?

Comment: `Plot[y'[x]/y[x] /. sol, {x, -2, 3}]`, where `sol` is the solution. You will have to have a definite solution, by which I mean you will have to plug in numbers for the parameters and for the constants of integration.

Comment: sol=DSolve[{(y''[x]/ y[x]) + 2 (y'[x]/ y[x])^2 - 
    2 (y'[x]/y[x]) + (1/y[x]) - 6 == 0,y[0] == 2, y'[0] == 3}, y, {x, 0, 2}]
But it doesn't work?!

Comment: For some values of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `DSolve` is unable to find a solution.  It works for this (`{a = 1, b = 2, c = 1, d = 2}`): https://i.stack.imgur.com/axmYV.png